# CDC in SS 2008 R2 not capturing data, but no errors either

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, cdc

First post, so I'll get right to it.  Thank you in advance for your answers and consideration.

I have full privileges on the database engine that the DB in question is running on, including sysadmin.

To the best of my knowledge, I have enabled this correctly according to documentation, doing the following:

1. Running the command `EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db` via a c# application
   that I am using as an interface to deal with setting up, recording,
   and comparing DML database changes.
2. From the same application, running the command

   ```
   EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table 
   @source_schema = N'dbo', 
   @source_name   = N'ORD_ATTACHMENTS', 
   @role_name     = NULL
   ```

I have verified that the DB in question is ready for CDC using `SELECT [name], database_id, is_cdc_enabled FROM sys.databases`.

The table's readiness I have also verified using `SELECT [name], is_tracked_by_cdc FROM sys.tables`.

Running `SELECT * FROM [msdb].[dbo].[cdc_jobs] WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID()` in the database context yields the following information for the capture job:

maxtrans: 7200
maxscans: 10
continuous: 1
pollinginterval: 5

retention and threshold are 0.

After inserting records into the table in question via SSMS, the related CDC table, though present, does not have any data in it. No errors were encountered, and the record was successfully added to the source table.

Additional information:

1. Database server used to use Windows fibers (lightweight pooling).  I
   have switched this off, reconfigured, and rebooted the server.
2. Database used to have compatibility set to SQL Server 2005 (90), but
   I have updated this to SQL Server 2008 (100).  Again rebooted the
   server.
3. I also set the Change Tracking property to true for the
   database in question, but I have since learned that this is
   irrelevant.

The source table has the following fields:

```
[AttachmentID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ORDNUM] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[FileName] [nvarchar](260) NOT NULL,
[FileContent] [varbinary](max) NULL,
[CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ORD_ATTACHMENTS_CreatedOn]    DEFAULT (getdate())
```

No fields are excluded from CDC for this table.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Best regards,
Chris.

Update 2016-09-20 15:15:
Ran the following:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE  
GO
```

Have now switched to a test DB to simplify matters.  Re-enabled the CDC on my new test table (fields are bigint PK identity field and an NVARCHAR(50) nullable field).  Still not working.  Also, the capture job has no history entries under SQL Server Agent.

Update 2016-09-20 20:09
Ran sp_MScdc_capture_job in the DB context.  This can be, depending on job settings, a continuously executing procedure.  Data was found in the CDC table upon running this.  Will try to figure out how to automatically engage this.

Update 2016-09-28 17:19
The capture job is scripted as follows:

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [cdc.CDCTest_capture]    Script Date: 2016-09-28 5:18:13 PM ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [REPL-LogReader]    Script Date: 2016-09-28 5:18:13 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'REPL-LogReader' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'REPL-LogReader'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'cdc.CDCTest_capture', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @notify_level_eventlog=2, 
    @notify_level_email=0, 
    @notify_level_netsend=0, 
    @notify_level_page=0, 
    @delete_level=0, 
    @description=N'CDC Log Scan Job', 
    @category_name=N'REPL-LogReader', 
    @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Starting Change Data Capture Collection Agent]    Script Date: 2016-09-28 5:18:14 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Starting Change Data Capture Collection Agent', 
    @step_id=1, 
    @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
    @on_success_action=3, 
    @on_success_step_id=0, 
    @on_fail_action=3, 
    @on_fail_step_id=0, 
    @retry_attempts=10, 
    @retry_interval=1, 
    @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
    @command=N'RAISERROR(22801, 10, -1)', 
    @server=N'AECON-SQL', 
    @database_name=N'CDCTest', 
    @flags=4
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Change Data Capture Collection Agent]    Script Date: 2016-09-28 5:18:14 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Change Data Capture Collection Agent', 
    @step_id=2, 
    @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
    @on_success_action=1, 
    @on_success_step_id=0, 
    @on_fail_action=2, 
    @on_fail_step_id=0, 
    @retry_attempts=10, 
    @retry_interval=1, 
    @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
    @command=N'sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job', 
    @server=N'AECON-SQL', 
    @database_name=N'CDCTest', 
    @flags=4
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'CDC capture agent schedule.', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @freq_type=64, 
    @freq_interval=0, 
    @freq_subday_type=0, 
    @freq_subday_interval=0, 
    @freq_relative_interval=0, 
    @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
    @active_start_date=20160920, 
    @active_end_date=99991231, 
    @active_start_time=0, 
    @active_end_time=235959, 
    @schedule_uid=N'd1fc7d85-c051-4b24-af84-5505308caaf0'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the SQL Server Agent job was not running, although SQL Server indicated that it was.  Turned this service on in the services console and was able to capture data in CDC.

Special thanks to LogicalMan who very patiently worked with me through all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Chris,

When you enable CDC at the DB and table level, a number of further objects are created underneath the cdc schema. Of importance are the various functions, the _CT table, and the two jobs cdc.XXXX_capture & cdc.XXXX_cleanup (where XXXX is the full name of the database).

From your description thus far, especially considering the latest update, the error appears to possibly be with the jobs themselves.
At the outset, and it might sound obvious, but do you have SQL Agent running on this instance? I only ask because it is not mentioned in your initial description.

If it is already running, then you will need to get in a little deeper.
If you navigate to your SQL Agent/Jobs folder (under SSMS), locate the capture job, right click and request it to be scripted, you should find the following.

4 calls:
sp_add_job @job_name=N'cdc.XXXX_capture'

sp_add_jobstep @step_name=N'Starting Change Data Capture Collection Agent'

sp_add_jobstep @step_name=N'Change Data Capture Collection Agent'

sp_add_jobschedule @name=N'CDC capture agent schedule.'

The second of those sp_add_jobstep calls is the one that executes the same code you indicates above, @command=N'sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job'.

You can attempt to kick the job off manually to see if that kicks it into life, or, at the very least, provides some data into the _CT table.

In addition, check the last of those calls above, the schedule, sp_add_jobschedule. This should also be enabled, with @freq_type=64 (to ensure it starts when the Agent starts).

Please provide the results of what you find in the response to assist further troubleshooting.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi LogicalMan.  Thank you for getting back to me.  I was able to manually get this running.  The second job step listed (Starting Change Data Capture Collection Agent) has a value of N'RAISERROR(22801, 10, -1)' for the command parameter.  The third step (Change Data Capture Collection Agent) has a value of N'sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job' for the command parm.  Thank you again.

Comment: Also, forgot to add that the freq_type is indeed 64.  Best regards,

Comment: No problems C Philp, CDC can be a real nightmare, I have been been incorporating this since 2008 and it can be somewhat fraught. Especially when you get deeper into it ! Any other issues, just ask, that's what we're all here for :)

Comment: Thank you Logical Man.  Is the value of N'RAISERROR(22801, 10, -1)' for the command parameter correct for the job 'Starting Change Data Capture Collection Agent'?

Comment: Yes Chris, this records the action of starting CDC. 

You can test the output of this by typing that command into an SSMS Query and you will see the following message appear: 

"Starting the Change Data Capture Collection Agent job. To report on the progress of the operation, query the sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions dynamic management view." 

The meat of the Job is contained inside step 2 as we discussed above.

Hope this assists.

Comment: Thank you again LogicalMan.  CDC does not capture data unless I first get everything running manually using sp_MScdc_capture_job.  Any thoughts?

Comment: So, once you kick that off manually, it runs without issues? If that's the case then it really does point to the job itself. All this does is kick that SProc off, and that then goes on it's merry way using a wait loop of 5 seconds to poll the various instances.  Can you just kick the job off manually to gain the same effect? What is the effects of that?

Comment: Hi Logical Man.  I suppose I could start the job manually, but I was hoping to have this automagically occur for the user since this was supposed to be a time and work saving application that I am creating.  Once the job is started, things work fine as far as populating the CDC tables are concerned.

Comment: OK then Chris. Did you check the schedule for the job at all? It should be set to start when SQL starts (64). I get the feeling that if that's the only trigger, then the process of creating a new CDC instance on a DB should then kick it off. Not sure what's happening with that though.  Tony

Comment: Hi Tony,  Please see updated complete job script listing above.  The freq_type parameter is 64 for the CDC capture agent schedule job.  Thank you again.

Comment: I also ran EXEC sys.sp_cdc_start_job @job_type = 'capture' in the DB context.  It yielded the following message: SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action.
However, when I ran this: EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; RECONFIGURE; EXEC sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1; RECONFIGURE;, the messages were: Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.  Reboot required perhaps?

Comment: Chris, that's looking promising. As you know, the job is kicked off by SQL Agent starting, and I wonder if a reboot might do the job. Do you have SQL Agent to startup automatically?  Cheers, Tony